# Show that $f(x) = \inf\{d(a,x) : a \in A \}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a non-empty set in a metric space $(X,d)$. Define $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \inf \{d(a,x) : a \in A \}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

If $f$ is continuous, then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0$ such that $$d(x,y) < \delta \implies \left| \inf \{d(a,x) : a \in A \} - \inf \{d(a,y) : a \in A \} \right| < \epsilon.$$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Understanding the answer to this other continuity question may help, as a similar technique can be used for your question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824049/showing-the-continuity-of-dx-fx

Comment: Not really how to *go from* there: perhaps how to *get* there.

Comment: I understand how to show that the other function it is continuous, the infimum behaves differently however.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the same proof technique can be applied to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use epsilon of the room technique. Fix $x,y\in X$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be given. Then there is $a\in A$ such that 
\begin{equation}
d\left(a,x\right)  \le f\left(x\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{align*}
f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right) & \le f\left(y\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}-d\left(a,x\right)\\
 & \le d\left(a,y\right)-d\left(a,x\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}
The first inequality comes from (1) and the second inequality
comes from the definition of $f$.

Since 
$$
\left|d\left(a,x\right)-d\left(a,y\right)\right|\le d\left(x,y\right),
$$
we see that 
$$
f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\le d\left(x,y\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
By similar principle, we have 
$$
\left|f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|\le d\left(x,y\right)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we obtain the conclusion.